# Ruby Volt routes not working correctly

Tags: ruby, voltrb

I am having some trouble with the routes in the Volt framework. I set up my route as follows:

```
client "/users/{{ id }}", component: 'users', controller: 'main', action: 'profile'
```

When I navigate to a page to see the profile, everything loads correctly, but the url is:

```
http://localhost:3000/users?action=profile&id=1234567890
```

I want the url to look like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/1234567890
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How are you navigating to the profiles page?

Comment: If I go to `http://localhost:3000/users/1234567890`, it changes the url to `http://localhost:3000/users?action=profile&id=1234567890` and loads the profile page correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, components are in views not in routes.

Are you using the users controller? If so I would  try this

```
client "/users/{{ id }}", controller: 'user', action: 'profile'
```